# Why do tables in postgresql get created in public schema despite a different search path?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

I am trying to have a specific role have access only to a specific schema.

I have schema public, and a schema python. I would like to set the default search_path for a role to schema python:

```
ALTER ROLE user2 SET search_path = python;
```

However when I try to create tables they still get placed into public schema, do I have to specify schema name every time when making tables?

```
CREATE TABLE table ();

-- vs.

CREATE TABLE python.table ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER ROLE ... SET ...` will take effect at next login. For an immediate effect in the current session (only), use `SET search_path TO myschema;`